Gazebo Harmonic/Garden/Fortress camera not working: couldn't find shared library
Goal:
I want to use an RGB camera in Gazebo Harmonic, Gazebo Garden or Gazebo Fortress.
Context:
I have a robot that needs a camera. I followed this tutorial, but couldn't get the camera to work.
The error I get in all the Gazebo versions that I have tried is:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SystemLoader.cc:94] Failed to load system plugin [libgazebo_ros_camera.so] : couldn't find shared library.

The full robot has a very large xacro file, so I tried to make a minimal working example. However, I still get the same error.
This is my xacro file:
<?xml version= "1.0" ?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="camera">
  
  <xacro:include filename="$(find camera)/description/materials.xacro"/>
  <xacro:include filename="$(find camera)/description/shapes.xacro"/>
  
  <xacro:property name="camera_length" value="0.05" />
  <xacro:property name="camera_width" value="0.2" />
  <xacro:property name="camera_height" value="0.1" />
  
  <link name="base_link">
    <xacro:box mass="1" x="${camera_length}" y="${camera_width}" z="${camera_height}" color="blue">
  <origin xyz="0 0 ${camera_height/2}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:box>
  </link>
  
  <link name="camera_lens">
    <xacro:cylinder_visual radius="${camera_height/2 - 0.01}" height="${0.02}" color="red">
      <origin xyz="0.01 0 0" rpy="0 0 0 "/>
    </xacro:cylinder_visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="camera_optical_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="camera_lens"/>
    <origin xyz="${camera_length/2} 0 ${camera_height/2}" rpy="${-pi/2} 0 ${-pi/2}" />
  </joint>
  
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
      <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.1</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>480</height>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.05</near>
          <far>8.0</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frame_name>camera_lens</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
      

Setup:
My host is Ubuntu 24.04. I am using ROS Humble inside a Docker container running Ubuntu 22.04. I tried both Gazebo Fortress and Gazebo Garden, but to no avail. I also tried ROS Jazzy and Gazebo Harmonic. I like working with Gazebo Harmonic the most, then Fortress and I like Garden the least.
You can find my files here: https://github.com/lgrvanlieshout/gazebo_camera_example
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
The problem is solved! I have updated the files on github so anyone can see how to implement a camera in Gazebo.

I think the tutorial you link to is for Gazebo Classic (i.e. 'old Gazebo'), and you are using Gazebo Sim (i.e. 'new Gazebo').
Have a look at this demo world for an example of the camera sensor.
You will have to use ros_gz_bridge or ros_gz_image to transfer the images to ROS 2, see here.

Thanks for the fast reply, this helped immensely!
